# .htaccess silent root to subdirectory remap

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to remap all root domain requests to a subfolder silently except `/user/` and `/admin/`. I have custom code under my root domain and want to install WordPress additionally which should be also available under the root domain.

My htaccess looks like this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

SetEnvIf Request_URI  ^(.*)$       section=public
SetEnvIf Request_URI  ^/user/.*$   section=user
SetEnvIf Request_URI  ^/admin/.*$  section=admin

# Link to WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:section} public

# ... How do I map to a subdirectory from here? ... #
```

**UPDATE**

I came accross the following code which is working almost like I need it, but if the file does not exists in wordpress, it repoints back to my code.

```
# Link public to WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:section} public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1

# Link public to WordPress root folder
RewriteCond %{ENV:section} public
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Comment: it is indeed installed in a subdirectory, but I need to access it from domain.com/

Comment: @anubhava I read it already. I just don't want to mess up my code with WordPress. I would need to copy index.php and .htaccess into my custom project

Comment: @anubhava the point is, I want to keep my own url handleing for /user and /admin, which I can't with the wordpress suggested method

Comment: These are actually not real subdirectories, but are handled by my own index.php. I would need to merge wordpresses index.php file with mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule just below `RewriteBase` line to skip 2 directories from all rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(user|admin)(/.*)?$ - [NC,L]
```

Comment: This will not work, since all the custom JS and CSS files are in some custom directories and will not get loaded.

Comment: Did you actually test it before saying it will not work? If js/css are in a custom dir say `/static/` then those requests won't be affected.

Comment: Look I have a website with some htaccess rules which map requests like /admin/ and /user/ to some URL parameter like index.php?section=admin. Now I have some other directories with media and JS files. 1. I cant replace my index.php nor my htaccess file with the one from wordpress, 2. If I install wordpress into the main dir and put all my other code into a subdir and add your htaccess line, it will break all my CSS since it will try to read it from domain.com/css/styles.css which is not existent.

Comment: How will `RewriteRule ^(user|admin)(/.*)?$ - [NC,L]` impact your css/js I am still unclear. Is your css URL using `domain.com/user/styly.css`?

Comment: No its not. Its `domain.com/css/style.css`. I don't have everything in one directory. I don't want to mix wordpress code with my own project.